# Haskell - Having trouble understanding a small bit of code

Tags: list, class, dictionary, haskell, anonymous-function

I am doing a school task where I am given a small bit of sample code which I can use later. I understand 90% of this code but there is one little line/function that I for the life of me can't figure out what it does (I am very new to Haskell btw).

Sample code:

```
data Profile = Profile {matrix::[[(Char,Int)]], moleType::SeqType, nrOfSeqs::Int, nm::String} deriving (Show)

nucleotides = "ACGT"
aminoacids = sort "ARNDCEQGHILKMFPSTWYVX"

makeProfileMatrix :: [MolSeq] -> [[(Char, Int)]]
makeProfileMatrix [] = error "Empty sequence list"
makeProfileMatrix sl = res
  where 
    t = seqType (head sl)
    defaults = 
      if (t == DNA) then
        zip nucleotides (replicate (length nucleotides) 0) -- Row 1
      else 
        zip aminoacids (replicate (length aminoacids) 0)   -- Row 2
    strs = map seqSequence sl                              -- Row 3
    tmp1 = map (map (\x -> ((head x), (length x))) . group . sort)
               (transpose strs)                            -- Row 4
    equalFst a b = (fst a) == (fst b)
    res = map sort (map (\l -> unionBy equalFst l defaults) tmp1)

{-Row 1: 'replicate' creates a list of zeros that is equal to the length of the 'nucleotides' string. 
This list is then 'zipped' (combines each element in each list into pairs/tuples) with the nucleotides-}

{-Row 2: 'replicate' creates a list of zeros that is equal to the length of the 'aminoacids' string.
This list is then 'zipped' (combines each element in each list into pairs/tuples) with the aminoacids-}

{-Row 3: The function 'seqSequence' is applied to each element in the 'sl' list and then returns a new altered list. 
In other words 'strs' becomes a list that contains the all the sequences in 'sl' (sl contains MolSeq objects, not strings)-}

{-Row 4: (transpose strs) creates a list that has each 'column' of sequences as a element (the first element is made up of each first element in each sequence etc.).
--}
```

I have written an explanation for each marked Row in the code (which I think so far is correct) but I get stuck when I try to figure out what Row 4 does. I understand the 'transpose' bit but I can't at all figure out what the inner map function does. As far as I know a 'map' function needs a list as a second parameter to function but the inner map function only has an anonymous function but no list to operate on. To be perfectly clear I don't understand what the entire inner line `map (\x -> ((head x), (length x))) . group . sort` does. Please help!

Bonus!:

Here is another piece of sample code that I can't figure out (never worked with classes in Haskell):

```
class Evol object where
 name :: object -> String
 distance :: object -> object -> Double
 distanceMatrix :: [object] -> [(String, String, Double)]
 addRow :: [object] -> Int -> [(String, String, Double)]
 distanceMatrix [] = []
 distanceMatrix object =
  addRow object 0 ++ distanceMatrix (tail object)
 addRow object num  -- Adds row to distance matrix
  | num < length object = (name a, name b, distance a b) : addRow object (num + 1)
  | otherwise = [] 
  where  
        a = head object
        b = object !! num


 -- Determines the name and distance of an instance of "Evol" if the instance is a "MolSeq".
instance Evol MolSeq where
 name = seqName
 distance = seqDistance

 -- Determines the name and distance of an instance of "Evol" if the instance is a "Profile".
instance Evol Profile where
 name = profileName
 distance = profileDistance
```

Especially this part:

```
addRow object num  -- Adds row to distance matrix
  | num < length object = (name a, name b, distance a b) : addRow object (num + 1)
  | otherwise = [] 
  where  
        a = head object
        b = object !! num
```

You don't have to explain this one if you don't want to I am just slightly confused as to what 'addRow' actually is trying to do (in detail).

Thanks!

Comment: It's cool, that you're interested in Haskell, but it would be better to extract the "bonus" part into a separate question, because these two questions are not related to each other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`map (\x -> (head x, length x)) . group . sort` is an idiomatic way of generating a histogram. When you see something like this that you don’t understand, try breaking it down into smaller pieces and testing them on sample inputs:

```
(\x -> (head x, length x)) "AAAA"
-- ('A', 4)

(group . sort) "CABABA"
-- ["AAA", "BB", "C"]

(map (\x -> (head x, length x)) . group . sort) "CABABA"
map (\x -> (head x, length x)) (group (sort "CABABA"))
-- [('A', 3), ('B', 2), ('C', 1)]
```

It’s written in *point-free* style as a composition of 3 functions, `map (…)`, `group`, and `sort`, but could also be written as a lambda:

```
\row -> map (…) (group (sort row))
```

For each row in the transposed matrix, it produces a histogram of the data in that row. You could get a more visual representation of this by formatting it and printing it out:

```
let
  showHistogramRow row = concat
    [ show $ head row
    , ":\t"
    , replicate (length row) '#'
    ]
  input = [3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6, 5, 3, 5]

putStr
  $ unlines
  $ map showHistogramRow
  $ group
  $ sort input

-- 1:   ##
-- 2:   #
-- 3:   ##
-- 4:   #
-- 5:   ###
-- 6:   #
-- 9:   #
```

As for this:

```
addRow object num  -- Adds row to distance matrix
  | num < length object = (name a, name b, distance a b) : addRow object (num + 1)
  | otherwise = [] 
  where  
        a = head object
        b = object !! num
```

`addRow` makes a list of the distances from the first element in `object` to each of the other elements. It uses indexing into the list in a sort of non-obvious way, when a simpler and more idiomatic `map` would suffice:

```
addRow object = map (\ b -> (name a, name b, distance a b)) object
  where a = head object
```

Ordinarily it’s good to avoid *partial* functions such as `head` because they can throw an exception on some inputs (e.g. `head []`). Here it’s fine, however, because if the input list is empty, then `a` will never be used, and so `head` will never be called.

`distanceMatrix` could be expressed with a `map` as well, because it’s just calling a function (`addRow`) on all the `tails` of the list and concatenating them together with `++`:

```
distanceMatrix object = concatMap addRow (tails object)
```

This could be written in point-free style too. `\x -> f (g x)` can be written as just `f . g`; here, `f` is `concatMap addRow` and `g` is `tails`:

```
distanceMatrix = concatMap addRow . tails
```

`Evol` just describes the set of types for which you can generate a `distanceMatrix`, including `MolSeq` and `Profile`. Note that `addRow` and `distanceMatrix` don‘t need to be members of this class, because they’re implemented entirely in terms of `name` and `distance`, so you could move them to the top level:

```
distanceMatrix :: (Evol object) => [object] -> [(String, String, Double)]
distanceMatrix = concatMap addRow . tails

addRow :: (Evol object) => [object] -> Int -> [(String, String, Double)]
addRow object = map (\ b -> (name a, name b, distance a b)) object
  where a = head object
```

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer! Now I understand! :)

Answer (score 3):

> the inner map function only has an anonymous function but no list to operate on

Given there's a function `f` of type `a -> b -> c`, which takes two arguments and returns a value of type `c`. If the `f` is called with one parameter it returns another function of type `b -> c`, which is going to take one more parameter and return a value. This is called currying.

This line:

```
map (map (\x -> ((head x), (length x))) . group . sort) (transpose strs)
```

can be transformed into:

```
map (\str -> (map (\x -> ((head x), (length x))) . group . sort) str)(transpose strs)
```

In this form, it might be cleared, that there's actually a list to operate on.

This function

```
(map (\x -> ((head x), (length x))) . group . sort)
```

is just a composition of `sort`, `group` and `map (\x -> ((head x), (length x)))`.

Let's see how it works on `[2,1,1,1,4]`:

`sort [2, 1, 1, 1, 4]` => `[1, 1, 1, 2, 4]`

`group [1, 1, 1, 2, 4]` => `[[1,1,1],[2],[4]]`

`map (\x -> ((head x), (length x)))` => `[(1,3),(2,1),(4,1)]`

It just returns a list of tuples. Every tuple contains an element as a first element and the number of occurrence as a second element.