# Function composition in Haskell example

Tags: haskell, function-composition

Assume b is a list of Strings and consider,

`map (map (\a -> ((head a), (length a))) . group . sort) (transpose b)`

I know what each individual function above does, but I'm having trouble seeing how the result is assembled. How would I go about figuring out the order in which the functions on this line run, with which parameters?

Specifically, I seem to understand that `(map (\a -> ((head a), (length a))) . group . sort)` is the the first parameter to the outer map and `(transpose b)` is the second parameter to the outer map.

But which are the parameters for the inner map? The inner map appears to just have one parameter: `(\a -> ((head a), (length a))) . group . sort)`. Where is the second parameter (the list to which to apply, element-wise, the function in the first parameter)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Haskell - Having trouble understanding a small bit of code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46131310/haskell-having-trouble-understanding-a-small-bit-of-code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have noticed is called [currying](https://wiki.haskell.org/Currying) and it's one of many great (or maybe not) aspects of Haskell functions. This is your code:

```
map (map (\a -> ((head a), (length a))) . group . sort) (transpose b)
```

Let's check the type of the first `map`:

```
map (\a -> ((head a), (length a))) :: [[a]] -> [(a, Int)]
```

We do so by typing this

```
:t map (\a -> ((head a), (length a)))
```

into **ghci**.

So know we know it's a function. It takes an element of type `[[a]]` and returns `[(a, Int)]`. Give the type of the map function is

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

This is perfectly fine. We have given `map` it's first argument, now, all that it need it's a proper list. What just happened with map is called [currying](https://wiki.haskell.org/Currying).

Now let's see, we have our `map` "connected" to `sort` and `group` through the `(.)` function.

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
```

Now let's change a little your piece of code so we can see better what's going on with the composition function.

```
map (\a -> ((head a), (length a))) . (group . sort)
```

I just separated `group` and `sort` with some parenthesis. But now we clearly see which elements act as arguments of the outer `(.)`.

We have the map in question, and another function, which results from the other composition. Again we have the *currying* in action, when we leave out the last argument:

```
map (\a -> ((head a), (length a))) . (group . sort)
:: Ord a => [a] -> [(a, Int)]
```

Finally the outer `map` takes the function from above and a list `(transpose b)`.

Answer (score 1):

It is given *implicitly*. If you write:

```
map (\a -> ((head a), (length a))) . group . sort
```

this is actually short for:

```
\b -> (map (\a -> ((head a), (length a))) . group . sort) b
```

which is equivalent to:

```
\b -> map (\a -> ((head a), (length a))) $ group $ sort b
```

or:

```
\b -> map (\a -> ((head a), (length a))) (group (sort b))
```

The `(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c` operator, thus composes two functions together in some sort of pipeline:

```
(.) f g x = f (g x)
```

Since we here write three functions separated by dots:

```
   map (\a -> ((head a), (length a))) . group . sort
-- \_________________ ______________/   \_ _/   \_ /
--                   v                    v       v
--                   f                    g       h
```

we have defined some sort of pipeline where an element is first processed through `h`, then the result is processed through `g`, and finally the result of that is processed through `f`.

Answer (score 1):

The dot is itself a function, defined like this:

```
(f . g) x = f (g x)
```

Let's use this equation in the first argument to the outer map:

```
map (\a -> (head a, length a)) . group . sort
= { definition of (.), with map (\a -> ...) as f and group . sort as g }
\x -> map (\a -> (head a, length a)) ((group . sort) x)
```

So, `map (\a -> ...) . group . sort` is a function which, when applied to argument `x`, supplies `(group . sort) x` as an argument to `map (\a -> ...)`.